# Difference between obj.key=value and obj.set(key, value)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

So while trying to update a document in mongoose, I realized that when I do `obj.key=value` to a document I obtained with `Model.findOne()`, it doesn'st assign the property to its value. But after trying obj.set(key, value), the property is assigned to its value in the document. So why is that? Usually when i do the first method to an object, the object gets the property. What is the `.set()` function? Does it have something to do with mongoose?

```
//this works
async function updateItem(){
        let updatedItem = await Item.findOne({name:req.body.itemName});
        Object.entries(req.body).forEach(elem=>{
            if(elem[0]!=="itemName"){
                updatedItem.set(elem[0], elem[1]);
            };
        });
    };
    updateItem();
});


//this doesn't work
async function updateItem(){
        let updatedItem = await Item.findOne({name:req.body.itemName});
        Object.entries(req.body).forEach(elem=>{
            if(elem[0]!=="itemName"){
                updatedItem.elem[0] = elem[1];
            };
        });
    };
    updateItem();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it related to reactive programming or not, but here is an explanation for how this works in Vuejs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I undestand now. It;s because of getters and setters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `updatedItem` is not an object, it's a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and to add items to a `Map` you need to use the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method.

Another thing to point out is that when you set `updatedItem.elem[0]`, you're *literally* trying to add the key `"elem[0]"` to `updatedItem`. To fix this, you need to use dynamic property notation with square brackets:

```
updatedItem[elem[0]] = elem[1];
```

This makes a new key with the *value* of `elem[0]`, instead of the *key* being `elem[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for the great help. Now I have an idea of what to search about even though i didn't understand something from the documentation.

Comment: Actually, what I'm going to ask doesn't have something to do with this entirely but it disturbed me while trying to update the Item. Before typing `Item.findOne()`, it was `Item.find()`, so it returned an array.And I typed `updatedItem[elem[0]] = elem[1]`, and it returns something like this `[{key:value, key:value, key: value}, key:value, key:value]` but didn't save to database. Is this array also a Map?

Comment: @EyePatch because there are key-value pairs inside a pair of square brackets, yes.